# Query exceeding log size, even after reducing complexity

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

Our Wishlist triggered emails are based on the entries in a huge table which is being populated by a query (after a weekly import). Unfortunately this query started crashing some weeks ago due to exceeding log size and our whole wishlist email system is therefore broken.

The query is joining the search terms and products of each customer with our product table, in order to pull all the information related to these deals. The query is now taking way over 30 minutes and therefore timing out. The source table has more than 13M rows and the products table has +- 90 000 rows.

I've already tried reducing the complexity of said query by dividing the query and reducing the amount of fields it needs to pull, going as low as only trying to pull 2 fields. Still too much... I've added WITH (NOLOCK) and I've tried pulling only for 10% of our customers at a time. Still way too long. I've been trying many many variations and it doesn't seem to matter how small I make the query, it will still time out.

This is the query as whole:

```
w.SubscriberKey,
w.WishlistSearchTerm,
w.ProductID,
p.Title,
p.SaleType,
p.TravelType,
p.IsPackage,
p.MetaTags,
p.StartDate AS "SaleMetaTags",
p.EndDate,
p.DestinationName,
p.DestinationType,
p.CountryName AS "Country",
p.DivisionName,
p.CityName AS "City",
p.SaleURL AS "URL",
p.Summary AS "ShortDescription",
p.MainParagraph,
p.SecondOpinion AS "HighlightsDescription",
p.WeLike AS "AdditionalText",
p.LeadRate AS "BestRate",
p.Currency AS "BestRateCurrency",
p.Discount AS "TopDiscount",
p.LeadImage1,
p.LeadImage2,
p.LeadImage3,
p.LeadImage4,
p.LeadImage5,
p.FetchTimestamp AS "ModifiedTimestamp",
p.ReasonToLove,
p.Latitude,
p.Longitude
FROM EXT_SALE_WISHLIST_TEMP w WITH (NOLOCK)
JOIN DIM_SALES_V4 p ON p.ProductID=w.ProductID
WHERE w.SubscriberKey BETWEEN 0 AND 5000000
```

But as said, I've already tried to make it as small as:

```
SELECT
w.SubscriberKey,
w.WishlistSearchTerm,
w.ProductID,
p.Title,
p.SaleType,
p.TravelType
FROM EXT_SALE_WISHLIST_TEMP w WITH (NOLOCK)
JOIN DIM_SALES_V4 p ON p.ProductID=w.ProductID
WHERE w.SubscriberKey BETWEEN 0 AND 5000000
```

Regrettably the person building this has left us some months ago and this is not quite my field of expertise.

Some more information:

- `SubscriberKey` and `ProductID` are primary keys
- The source table is a temporary one and the target table is empty
- The query is set to `Overwrite`
- I've added `WHERE w.SubscriberKey BETWEEN 0 AND 5000000` at last but I've tried many time without this clause
- I just need to get this query under 30 minutes runtime or divide it in as many queries as needed, it doesn't matter if in total it takes a couple of hours to run as it is a weekly process

Comment: First, note that "crashing" and "timing out" are very different things. NOLOCK is not a consequence-free magic - so you probably should not use that until you are prepared to address those consequences. Lastly, "set to overwrite" means nothing to your reader but implies a larger process. You likely have multiple issues here - starting with tuning your query/database and continuing on to the process that uses this resultset.

Comment: You can find many discussions of how to approach query optimization (tuning) - here is [one](https://www.brentozar.com/sql/sql-server-performance-tuning/). That is difficult to do in a forum such as this and you should consider hiring a replacement sooner rather than putting it off any longer.

Comment: A Select statement usually does not generate transaction logs if no temp tables are involved so not sure how the query caused exceeding log size.

Comment: I think this is just a generic Salesforce error code for when the query runs for longer than 30 minutes.